# Flutter TextFieldInput Value not updating after setState method

Tags: flutter, dart, input-field

I have a simple code as below:

```
 TextFormField(
                      initialValue: otp ?? "",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
                    Text(otp ?? ""),
                    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
```

now I am calling an api from a function where the `api` gives an otp and that needs to be displayed in the `TextFieldInput` which is not showing at all ! but it is displayed in a `Text Widget`. What can be the issue.

```
void processCoupon() async {
    try {
      if (_terms) {
        print("processing mobile number !");
        var data = {"mobile": _authModel.mobile};
        ApiCall().postData(data, cApi).then((result) {
          print(result);
          if (result["data"] != null) {
            print(result["data"]["otp"]);
            setState(() {
              otp = result["data"]["otp"].toString();
            });
           }
        });
      } else {
        print("terms not agreed !");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what you get `print(result["data"]["otp"]);` ?

Comment: the otp number.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                  initialValue: otp ?? "",
                ),
```

change with

```
TextEditingController _editingController=TextEditingController();
TextFormField(initialValue: otp ?? "",controller: _editingController,);
```

and

```
  setState(() {
          otp = result["data"]["otp"].toString();
        });
```

change with

```
 setState(() {
          otp = result["data"]["otp"].toString();
          _editingController.text=otp;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `TextEditingController` for your `TextField`:

```
  // create a controller for the TextField
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

2. Assign the `controller` to your `TextField`:

```
     TextFormField(
          initialValue: otp ?? "",
          // assign the controller to the TextField
          controller: controller, // new line
        ),
        SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
        Text(otp ?? ""),
        SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
```

3. Assign the `otp` string to the `Text` property of the `controller`:

```
   void processCoupon() async {
    try {
      if (_terms) {
        print("processing mobile number !");
        var data = {"mobile": _authModel.mobile};
        ApiCall().postData(data, cApi).then((result) {
          print(result);
          if (result["data"] != null) {
            print(result["data"]["otp"]);
            setState(() {
              otp = result["data"]["otp"].toString();
              // set the otp to be the text the controller has
              controller.text = otp; // new line
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        print("terms not agreed !");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that the InitialValue is only used in the first contruction, after you should update with a TextController.

Declare:

```
var otpController = TextEditingController();
```

Add the controller to your TextFormField:

```
controller: otpController,
```

Update the text:

```
setState(() {
    otpController.text = result["data"]["otp"].toString();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the way we can use the `TextController` for this purpose but the issue is that the form is pretty lengthy and this is where we can't use this method as a object needs to be used. the problem was that they `inital value can be passed` but when we try to update that value, for reflecting the value, we need to also update the key so that the `inputfield` will update as well. I just added the below value and Voila ! everything is now working fine.

```
TextFormField(

key: Key(otp), <--- this line was added
                      initialValue: otp ?? "",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
                    Text(otp ?? ""),
                    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20.0)),
```